# Should I use normalized frequencies or raw frequencies when conducting Log-likelihood test to compare two corpora with differing text lenghts?

Tags: corpora

Analyzing multiword expressions and I want to compare two corpora of similar sizes, but these corpora differ in average text length. For example average text length in Corpus A. is 300 while it is 600 in Corpus B. Therefore I normalized the frequencies with this formula: frequency of target structure / the length of an individual text multiplied by 400. Should I put normalized frequencies  or raw frequencies in Log-likelihood test ?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. After a thorough search, I have concluded that the log-likelihood test is the most suitable method for comparing corpora with similar text lengths. It is not recommended to use normalized values of frequency as the official website advises. However, a possible solution would be trimming the lengths of the texts in two corpora to the same length, but in my case, it would result in a loss of essential data for my analysis. Therefore, I ended up using the Mann-Whitney U test instead and compared means.

Answer (score 1):

When conducting a Log-likelihood test to compare two corpora with differing text lengths, it is better to use normalized frequencies. This is because raw frequencies can be misleading when comparing corpora of different sizes, as the frequencies will naturally be higher in larger corpora. Normalizing the frequencies allows for a more fair and accurate comparison between the two corpora.

In your case, you have already normalized the frequencies using the formula:

```
normalized frequency = (frequency of target structure / length of an individual text) * 400
```

This normalization process accounts for the differences in text length and enables you to compare the corpora more accurately. Therefore, you should input the normalized frequencies into the Log-likelihood test.

Answer (score 0):

It works similar to a Chi-Square test, and the frequencies do not need to be normalised. For more information [see this page](https://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/llwizard.html), which describes the procedure (and also gives more references in case you need them).